# Using Chartkick in Rails 4.0

Tags: charts, ruby-on-rails-4

How can i use Chartkick in rails 4.0.

in Gem I added:

> gem "chartkick"

and in my view for example i added this:

```
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
```

but the page only show Loading...
generated Html:

```
<div id="chart-1" style="height: 300px; text-align: center; color:
#999; line-height: 300px; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">   Loading... </div> <script type="text/javascript">   new Chartkick.PieChart("chart-1", {"Football":10,"Basketball":5}, {}); </script>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Be sure to include the JavaScript files before the charts.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

Comment: In rails 4 application.js i added //= require chartkick and //= require jsapi. but the problem was not solved

Comment: I found the solution. I must add //= require jsapi
and //= require chartkick on top of application.js.

Answer (score 21):

To get chartkick working in Rails 4, I did the following:

**1.** Added chartkick gem to my Gemfile (bundle install)

```
gem 'chartkick'
```

**2.** Downloaded [Google jsapi file](https://www.google.com/jsapi) into my vendor directory

```
/railsapp/vendor/assets/javascripts/jsapi.js
```

**3.** Added chartkick and jsapi to my application.js

```
//= require jsapi
//= require chartkick
```

After that, charts showed up on a consistent basis.

Answer (score 5):

**Loading your charts superfast**

i am using highcharts here as it do not require you to connect each time to google server

add this gem

```
gem "chartkick"
```

then download highchart.js from here http://www.highcharts.com/download

paste the file in your 
   app/vendor/assets/javascript/highchart.js

open your application.js and require these two files

```
//= require highcharts.js
//= require chartkick
```

after this you are good to go and your charts will load within a blink

Answer (score 4):

There are actually 2 ways to solve this, refer to the "Installation" guidelines: http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/

For Google Charts, use:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

If you prefer Highcharts, use:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "path/to/highcharts.js", "chartkick" %>
```

For those who are thinking of using jsapi offline, you cant really, even if you have downloaded jsapi.js, it still does a further load to google. You are just breaking the terms:

Extract from: [Google Charts FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline)

> Can I use charts offline?
>
> No; your computer must have live access to http://www.google.com/jsapi
>   in order to use charts. This is because the visualization libraries
>   that your page requires are loaded dynamically before you use them.
>   The code for loading the appropriate library is part of the included
>   jsapi script, and is called when you invoke the google.load() method.
>   Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.load or
>   google.visualization code to use offline.
>
> Can I download and host the chart code locally, or on an intranet?
>
> Sorry; our terms of service do not allow you to download and save or
>   host the google.load or google.visualization code.

Answer (score 0):

somehow I needed to add these three lines to get things working...but still I get a few warnings... In v3.0 they say they have some breaking changes in regards to jsapi... confusing.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="chartkick.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js", "chartkick" %>
```