# Chartkick + Rails 4 "undefined method `pie_chart' for #<#<Class:..."

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts

I am new to Rails. I followed the documentation and this example: [Using Chartkick in Rails 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144640/using-chartkick-in-rails-4-0/19152504#19152504)
but I cannot get Chartkick to work. I get undefined method pie chart. My js looks like this:

```
//= require chartkick
//= require jsapi
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

I have tried including the javascript_include in both the application kayout and the show page. <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>

Any ideas? Thanks all. I really do appreciate every bit of help I get here.

Comment: Can you paste the full error message?  Also, be sure to include the Javascript before the charts.

Comment: Sure. NoMethodError in Static#home
Showing /app/views/static/home.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `pie_chart' for #<#<Class:0x007fbf3b27d7b8>:0x007fbf3b744bc0>
Extracted source (around line #7):
          
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>

Comment: Sounds like you may need to restart your rails server.

Comment: Thats when I get undefined method pie_chart

Comment: Also, be sure to add the gem to your Gemfile and run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, since Chartkick runs as an engine, I did not need to add // include chartkick into the application js file- I removed it and it worked like a charm. That means that the steps to get Chartkick to work in Rails 4 are:

- add `gem 'chartkick'` to your Gemfile
- add `<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>` to app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: @SNEHPANDYA where did you add the line above

Comment: layout.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your chartkick's `javascript_include_tag` - `'data-turbolinks-track' => true`. Also have a `jquery-turbolinks gem` installed (with it's correct structure of scripts requiring in `application.js` file). Finally restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

write

#= require active_admin/base

require chartkick

in active_admin.js.coffee

and call direct jsapi from google like this in partial file.._items.html.ebr in app/views/items folder

javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"

pie_chart order, library: {pieSliceText: 'value'}

and then call this partial file like this

div class: 'custom-class' do

```
        h3 'Items'
        @item = Item.group(:menu_id).count #whatever data you pass to chart
        render partial: 'items/items', locals: {item: @item}
      end
```